# Blending in opengl compute shaders

Tags: opengl, gpgpu, raytracing

Since imageAtomicAdd (which seems to be the only real atomic "read-modify-store" function that operates on images) is only available for 32bit integers, I don't see any sensible way to accumulate multiple color values from different shader invocations in one pixel.

The only somewhat reasonable way to do this that I can see is to use 32bit per color (128bit per RGBA pixel), add 8bit color values up, hope that it doesn't overflow and clamp to 8bit afterwards.
This seems wasteful and restrictive (only pure additive blending?)

Accumulating in other data structures also doesn't solve the issue, since shared variables and ssbos also only seem to support atomicAdd and also only on integers.

There are two reasons that make me think I am probably missing something:
1. Every pathtracer that allows for concurrent intersection testing (for example for shadow rays) has to solve this issue so it seems like there must be a solution.
2. All kinds of fancy blending can be done in fragment shaders, so the hardware is definitely capable of doing this.

Is everyone just writing pathtracers that have a 1:1 shader invocation:pixel mapping?

Comment: Won't the final color be incorrect if you blend stuff in random order?

Comment: That depends on the blend function. Additive blending (which is what I want to achieve) is order independent.

Comment: Then imageAtomicAdd is enough, right? I would understand if they decided to not allow atomic operation that do not make sense.

Comment: No imageAtomicAdd only works the whole 32bit word. Modifying the 4*8bit RGBA representation per color like a fragment shader does it is not supported. Colors will overflow into each other, alpha values don't make any sense, etc.

Comment: Ha you're right. I don't know if it's possible or not in a compute shader then. I think Fragment shader don't need that kind of atomic writes because their execution is always strongly ordered (even when the blending could be order independent).

Comment: I don't think there are any order guarantees in fragment shaders beyond the order of draw calls, so there needs to be some kind of locking mechanism or atomic read-modify-write capability for framebuffers. Anyway, I still haven't found anything that points to this being exposed in compute shaders, so I'll have to redesign a little or go the 32bit per color route. The latter may not be as bad as I imagine it to be, but it is pretty wasteful in terms of memory.